# Python - Function creation with arguments that aren't recognised

Tags: python, function

I have this code, but if I type `nam(2,3)` it doesn't do anything. What is the problem?

```
 def nam(a, y):
    a = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    e = a+y
    print(e)
```

EDIT

How to make the insert only integers not be an infinite loop and just declare it once and expect a valid input??

```
def aa(nam, x):
    na = (nam)
    while True:
        try:
            age = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print("Insert only integers")
            continue
        else:
            break
    print(na,age)


aa("nic", "adeg")
```

Comment: So what happens instead? What did you *expect* to happen? **Where** are you running this code? Note that many an IDE console does not implement input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `input()`, so the program is waiting for the user input. Moreover, the function will use this user input to override the `a` and `y` values it was passed, which probably isn't want you meant to do. Remove the `input` calls and you should be OK:

```
def nam(a, y):
    a = int(a)
    y = int(y)
    e = a+y
    print(e)
```

Comment: can u check the question again and help with the edited part ?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the arguments to the function but then asking the user for input (which is why "nothing happens". The program waits for that input).

Simply use the arguments you are passing in.

```
def nam(a, y):
    e = a + y
    print(e)

nam(2, 3)
```